# setting an equation using text *and* margin

Tags: equations

While setting lecture notes I use a quite wide margin (two side) with a relatively narrow text width. Tables and figures are allowed to use the complete
width, if necessary. Now I would like to set an equation using the whole width, which is nearly successful (see MWE below). Only the equation tag sticks still to the textwidth. How can I change this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[textwidth=12cm,
            textheight=22cm,
            includehead=true,
            includefoot=true,
            headsep=1.2\baselineskip,
            marginparsep=0.8cm,
            marginparwidth=4.2cm,
            inner=2cm,
            top=1.5cm
            ]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
%
\begin{equation} 
 E = m c^2
\end{equation}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{addmargin*}{0pt}{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\begin{equation} 
 EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE = mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm c^2
\end{equation}
\end{addmargin*}
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works with the `changepage` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[textwidth=12cm,
            textheight=22cm,
            includehead=true,
            includefoot=true,
            headsep=1.2\baselineskip,
            marginparsep=0.8cm,
            marginparwidth=4.2cm,
            inner=2cm,
            top=1.5cm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
%
\begin{equation}
 E = m c^2
\end{equation}
%
\blindtext
\vskip-0.5\baselineskip
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\begin{equation}
 EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE = mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm c^2
\end{equation}
\end{adjustwidth*}
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works (nearly) perfectly. Many thanks! --- The only drawback is, that I get a page break in my original document between the equation and the preceding text. And the \vskip-macro seems to be essential, as without it the odd/even page discrimination does not work correctly (even with the strict-option).